# Using ng-transclude and ng-include in a nested angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

TL;DR: On this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkDRvq4S3fIO9R2TWkLH?p=preview), why does the second directive not render the included template?

This example is simplified, but I actually have a usecase where doing what I am about to attempt makes sense.

I have an Angular directive that uses ng-include to wrap a provided template into some other HTML using ng-include and and ng-transclude. It works fine on its own.

```
.directive('content', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: 'contentCtrl',
        template: '' +
          '<div class="foo">' +
          '  <div ng-transclude></div>' +
          '</div>',
        scope: {
        }
    };  
}])

.directive('contentInner', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^content', 
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
        },
        template: '' +
          '<div class="body">' +
          '  <div class="close" ng-click="close()">' +
          '    <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>' +
          '    <span>Close</span>' +
          '  </div>' +
          '  <div ng-transclude ></div>' +
          '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          scope.close = function() {
              controller.close();
          };
        }
    };
}])
```

But then I have another directive that is trying to use this first directive and that's where it breaks down and fails silently.

```
.directive('box', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            template: '@'
        },
        template: '' +
          '<div>' +
          '  <content>' +
          '    <content-inner>' +
          '      <div ng-include ng-src="{{template}}"/>' +
          '    </content-inner>' +
          '  </conent>' +
          '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          //$compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Looking at the generated source I can see that it looks like this

```
<div template="'template.html'">
  <div class="foo">
    <div ng-transclude="">
      <div class="body ng-scope">
        <div class="close" ng-click="close()">
          <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
          <span>Close</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-transclude="">
          <div ng-include="" ng-src="'template.html'" 
              class="ng-scope" src="'template.html'">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the reference to the template in the ng-include at the innermost level is there but it is not getting rendered. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkDRvq4S3fIO9R2TWkLH?p=preview).

So where did my template go in the second directive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I managed to fix your problem, by changing two things. See it here: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3tVAg?p=preview).

When using `"@"` for a directive scope, the attribute is passed to the scope as a string, so you shouldn't put the value between simple quotes.

Also, I replaced `<div ng-include ng-src="{{template}}"/>` in the template with `<div ng-include="template"/>` because from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude), ng-include doesn't use src when used as an attribute (but I don't understand why it worked in your first example...)

Hope that helps anyway.